# ActiveRecord One-to-Many update error when insert a traversal

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Given two ActiveRecord models with One-to-Many association,
User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :books, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

then in app.rb, the problem will appear

```
class ProblemApp
    dbconfig = YAML.load(File.open("config/database.yml").read)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig['development'])

    user = User.first
    (1..5).each do |price|
        user.books.each do |book|   ####### bug line !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        end                     ####### bug line !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        return nil unless (book = user.books.find_by_id 1)
        puts book.name.to_s + " + " + price.to_s

        book.price = price  # change attr
        puts book.save      # save changing

        book = user.books.first
        puts book.name.to_s + " - " + book.price.to_s
        puts "================="
    end
end
```

the console output:

```
Running... 
Ruby + 1
true
Ruby - 1
=================
Ruby + 2
true
Ruby - 1
=================
Ruby + 3
true
Ruby - 1
=================
Ruby + 4
true
Ruby - 1
=================
Ruby + 5
true
Ruby - 1
=================
```

The price of model wouldn't update when insert a books.each block before each changing operation. However, the price in database can update when execute save line. When remove the two lines of the block, the problem disappear.

more info at [my github](https://github.com/SanCoder-Q/activerecord_problem)
Anybody know why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should update the ActiveRecord::Relation for User before read the books.

Try to add `user.reload` after `book.save`.

Click [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) to get more information.

Comment: It seems the ```reload``` method is the best solution for now. i can just use ```user.books.reload``` to update books field but entire ```user```. Thank a lot.